# Break on main function but not crash

Tags: ios, xcode

Everytime I run my app on either simulator or real device, it break on the main function like this:

[image]

but, I click *Continue program execution*, my app never crashs.

I can't remember when this situation appeared, my Xcode version is 6.3.2 (6D2105).

Any ideas?